# error - could not find driver , while fetching data from database in laravel

Tags: php, sql-server, database, laravel

I am getting following error -

**`could not find driver (SQL: select * from [customer] order by [id] desc)`**

```
 'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'Customer'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'SA'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', '**********'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
    ],
```

I have also change the default option in database file like below -

```
  'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlsrv'),
```

After doing all I am facing mentioned error .

Comment: Looks like the `sqlsrv` driver is missing from your server

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention one point , This error getting only working with MS SQL server and It's working fine with MYSQl

Comment: I think you might have not installed that specific database. In case if you have installed then make sure to check whether that database driver is supported in laravel framework

Comment: You need various extra bits to get SQL Server running under PHP that dont come out of the box. [See this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: so how can I check driver ? @Jamesking56

Comment: @HitendraPatil You can follow this tutorial to install the driver: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-2017 Assuming you are running Linux

Comment: @Jamesking56 thanks ..... But Actually I already gone through same. I have create DB and Table , insert data as well using ms sql server. But while connecting to laravel I am getting error .